# How to retrieve the source links of all images on your phone (Phonegap)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

There are multiple Phonegap Plugins that allow you to select [one](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/242) or [multiple](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/807) images from your phone or to take a new picture with your phone [camera](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/242).

For example, with Cordova ImagePicker we could write the following to prompt the user to select multiple images from its device:

```
window.imagePicker.getPictures(
    function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
    }};
```

However, little is being sad about creating your own in-app image viewer seeded by the pictures from your phone.

An example would be the instagram app when selecting a new image: it by default shows a preview of the pictures of your phone within the app instead of popping out a new (native) window.

I am therefore searching for a way to get all the source links of the images on the phone without prompting the user.

Does anyone have an idea how to handle this?